# How to publish 2 sets of tests results on Azure Devop?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, continuous-integration, automated-tests

We have a git repository that contains .Net code(backend) and since recently typescript code(angular, front-end).

When we added the angular test execution, it appears that the initial .net tests are not correctly published. From my test, it seems that only the last publish is conserved.

How can we keep both of them? It's important because it's used in a PR and we don't want ton miss anything.

Here is how we publish the .Net tests:

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testResults'
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true
      testRunTitle: '.Net tests'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
```

and here how we publish the Angular tests:

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Angular test results'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/angular-test/results
      testRunTitle: Angular
      testResultsFormat: JUnit
      testResultsFiles: '**/TESTS*.xml'
```

How can we ensure both tests results are considered in Azure Devop:
[image]
(here you see only the angular tests and its (few) tests. You also see there has been two tests run).

I taught about doing only once the `PublishTestResults` task, but since they have different format(.net is NUnit, while angular is JUnit), it will not work.

Comment: What is the output from the publish test results task? You can publish multiple sets of test results. Are you actually publishing your test results to the location `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testResults'`?

Comment: @DanielMann Not sure what you mean? The tests results from .Net tests  is an xml file(NUnit format) in testResults, and the tests results of Angular tests is an xml file(JUnit format) in angular-test.  .Net tests have been working for years, and now that I just added this new publish for angular tests, I only see the angular tests results in azure.

Comment: When your tests run, they create files *somewhere*. I am asking if you have **confirmed** that the test results are being created in the location that you think they are.

Comment: @DanielMann Unfortunately, repository get cleaned after execution, but since the angular tests appears properly in azure devop, and if I disable the angular test publish, the .net tests results are published, I think the path are corrects.

Comment: from Microsoft docs: "At present, the code coverage reporting functionality provided by this task is limited, and it does not merge coverage data. If you provide multiple files as input to the task, only the first match is considered."  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v1?view=azure-pipelines#is-code-coverage-data-merged-when-multiple-files-are-provided-as-input-to-the-task-or-multiple-tasks-are-used-in-the-pipeline)